# solving natural log inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-writing, logarithms, proof-explanation

How can I show that

$0 \le (\sum_{x=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x})-ln(n) \le 1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Do I raise both sides by $e$ or perhaps take integral of both sides? If so, I'm still not quite sure where to go from there

Comment: Use $\ln n =\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \; dx$ and think about the graph of the sum and the graph of $1/x.$

Comment: @B.Goddard it seems to give 1 as the higher bound not $1-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: well the property is wrong as for n=1, it gives $1 \le 0$

Comment: If you have the rectangle for $1/1$ abutting the $y$-axis, then the graph of $1/x$ is above all the rectangles.  There are little triangle-ish pieces between the curve and the stair steps.  Each triangle-oid is above the next, so you can push them all to the left, into the $1\times 1$ square.  If you stop at $n$, there is a black space in the bottom of that first square, and it's area is at least $1/n.$

Answer (score 0):

Start with a basic integration of $\frac{1}{x}$ from $n-1$ to $n$.

$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Since $\frac1n$ is the lower limit of this decreasing function, the value of the integrand will always be greater than or equal to $0$ through out the interval of integration.

Now if you sum this up from $n = 1$ to $n-1$, you get

$$\int_{1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}...\frac{1}{n-1}\right) - \frac{1}{x} dx$$

$$\int_{1}^{n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\right)- \frac{1}{x}dx$$

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\right) - \log n$$

Sum of non negative quantities always give a non negative quantity, and hence the above quantity is $\geq 0$, thus proving the first part of the inequality.

For the second part, sketch out the box using the graph of $\frac1x$ from $n$ to $n+1$ on x-axis with $\frac1n$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ on y-axis. Now if you shade the area of this box that pertains to the integrand in the first equation, you'll notice that it is always less than equal to the area of the box.

$$\left(\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{x}dx\right) \leq A_{box}$$

$$A_{box} = \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac1{n+1}\right)(n+1 - n) = \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac1{n+1}\right)$$

Similarly as before, sum the inequality on both sides from $1$ to $n-1$ to get

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\right) - \log n \leq (1 -\frac12) + (\frac12 - \frac13) + (\frac13 - \frac14) ... (\frac1{n-1} -\frac1n) $$

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\right) - \log n \leq 1 - \frac1n $$

Thus, proving the second part of the inequality

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}<\ln (n+1)<\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$
which maybe is what you exactly want.

Notice that we only need to prove
$$\frac{1}{k+1}<\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})<\frac{1}{k}\quad\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

which can be yielded by
$$(\frac{k+1}{k})^k<e<(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k+1}$$

The inequality can be revealed by monotonicity of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ .

And for this we have an interesting elementary proof as follows,

> we have
> $$\ln \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right) = \int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx>\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{n+2}\int_{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\,dx > n\int_{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
> Now add
> $$n\ln \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right) = n\int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
> We get
> $$\left(n+1\right)\ln \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right) > n\int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx = n\ln \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)$$
> which means $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ is strictly increasing.
> The monotonicity of the other sequence can be similarly proved.

Added:(another elementary proof of the monotonicity)

> $$ n\ln \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n}{x+n}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}+1}\,dx$$
>
> hence it is clear that the RHS is increasing, since for any $x\in(0,1)$ and any $N>n$ we have
> $$ \frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}+1}<\frac{1}{\frac{x}{N}+1}$$
> so we have $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ is strictly increasing.
> The monotonicity of the other sequence can be similarly proved.